# How to make a byte[1] from a byte?

Tags: java, casting

Is there a better way to get a `byte[1]` from a `byte` than this?

```
byte given_byte = 0x12;
byte[] wanted_byte  = new byte[1];
wanted_byte[0] = given_byte;
```

I have `given_byte`. It seems unnecessary to use two lines to define `wanted_byte`.

Comment: Please note that what you're doing is not casting.

Comment: You're creating a new (short) `byte` array and copying the value of the `byte` into it. They're now separate items.

Comment: @Andreas You're creating an array with one element. Casting is telling the compiler that an object it knows has one type should now be represented as another type. ex: final final Object o = "Hi"; final String s = (String) o; The second line has a cast from Object to String.

Comment: Yes, what *is* it that you're doing? What's the requirement? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @EJP Muhammad and Tony seem to have understood perfectly what I was trying to solve and answered my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
byte[] wanted_byte = new byte[]{given_byte};
```

Or as **Holger** said:

```
byte[] wanted_byte = {given_byte};
```

Comment: Snap!, except you missed the semi-colon off the end. :)

Comment: Or simply `byte[] wanted_byte = {given_byte};`

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] wanted_byte = new byte[] {given_byte};
```

Comment: -1 because you saw another poster answered the same thing minus the semicolon and rather than fix that you posted your own.

Comment: @mah: He noticed that _after_ writing his own answer.

Comment: @mah, You having a bad day? Sheesh

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I'm not having a bad day at all, but I find the way you went about this to be of poor form.

Comment: @mah, given that both answers are only 1 minute apart, it is possible that both simply given the same answer, one without the semicolon, one with - It is a possibility...

Comment: @munyul and Andreas, yes it's a definite possibility however there are better options that can be taken after one has noticed this. In my own case, I have more than once simply corrected the answer that was there first and deleted my own.

Comment: @mah, now you've seen that not everyone reacts the same way you do. If he did what you claim, then -1 to him, but I doubt that he did (looking at the time difference).

Comment: @mah Seeing as I didn't go about it in the way you you seem to have conjured out of thin air, presumably based on your own personal thical framework. Do one!

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
public byte[] cerateByteArray(byte... arr){
    return arr;
}
public void sample(){
    byte b1 = 0;
    byte b2 = 1;
    byte[] wanted_byte = createByteArray(b1,b2);
}
```

Or the short way:

```
byte[] b = {0x01, 0x02};
```

Comment: Since the question is asking about how to reduce lines of code... how does this solution address it?